# How to incorporate HTML tags for styling certain parts of localized strings (Polymer)

Tags: html, css, localization, polymer

The web application I am working on uses resource strings for localization. The issue I am having is with styling certain parts of these strings. Let's say I want to display this string:

> **user1234** created a new document.

So in the resource file it would be localized like so:

```
{username} created a new document.
```

The issue is I also need `<b></b>` tags around `{username}`. I can't put these tags in the html file because I need it to apply just to the username, not to the whole localized string. So unless I split up the string into two localized strings (which I should definitely *not* do, because other languages do not necessarily have the same sentence structure), I have to put these html tags in the localized string itself:

```
<b>{username}</b> created a new document.
```

Even if we disregard best practices for a moment (of which I have [read briefly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255164/should-putting-html-tags-into-localization-files-be-avoided)) and go with this, this solution isn't working for me. I believe this is because the application is using Polymer (this seems to work with Angular). So if we stick by the following two requirements:

1. Use Polymer
2. Have the whole string together as one resource string

then there doesn't seem to be a way to style certain parts of the string. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by setting the resource string to the inner HTML of the element which contains the string. So let's say the div containing the text has `id="textElem"`, in the Javascript I set the inner HTML like so:

```
this.$.textElem.innerHTML = this.localize('user_created_document', 'username', this.username)
```

I suppose I should have specified in the question that my previous attempts of setting the string were just (a) simply binding the string to the property of an object and referencing that in the HTML, and (b) localizing the string directly in the HTML, neither of which worked.